# Do C++ classes solve function overwriting?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, thread-safety

So I have two threads running, each calls the same function. I have either run into a race situation or the value got messed up in the function SomeFunction. I assume that each thread will not have its own copy of SomeFunction, correct?

```
DWORD Thread1() {
INT dwA = 4;
SomeFunction(dwA);
}

DWORD Thread2() {
INT dwB = 5;
return SomeFunction(dwB);
}

DWORD SomeFunction(DWORD *dwVal) {
// do some lengthy operations with dwVal here
return dwVal;
}
```

My question is, instead of the above, if I put the SomeFunction in a class and create a new class in each thread, would that solve the problem of each thread calling the same function and thus stomping over the other thread's value that may have called SomeFunction() before? Does each thread get its own copy of the SomeFunction in memory to avoid this issue?

```
class.h:
class CDatabase
{
public:
    CClass();
    ~CClass();   
    DWORD CClass::SomeFunction(DWORD *dwVal);
};


class.cpp
CClass::CClass() {}
CClass::~CClass() {}
DWORD CClass::SomeFunction(DWORD *dwVal) {
// do some lengthy operations with dwVal here
return dwVal;
}
```

And is this what I'd put in each thread?

```
DWORD Thread1() {
INT dwA = 4;
CClass *m_CDatabase = new CClass();
DWORD rv = m_CDatabase->SomeFunction(dwA);
delete m_CDatabase;
return rv;
}

DWORD Thread2() {
INT dwA = 5;
CClass *m_CClass = new CClass();
DWORD rv = m_CClass->SomeFunction(dwA);
delete m_CClass;
return rv;    
}
```

If I'm not being clear enough, please let me know.

Comment: Classes change *nothing* in regard to race conditions.

Comment: Maybe "race" is not the correct word I should be using.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and treat them as errors. If your code snippets are indicative of anything, you forgot an ampersand, like so `SomeFunction(&dwA)`

Comment: Two threads running the same code is not an issue. Two threads operating on the same data without appropriate synchronization is an issue.

Comment: What does you function do except for operating on dwal? If it doesn't touch any other shared state, just pass dwal by value (and return it by value) and this completely solves your problem.

Comment: @JeffR - a race condition is one manifestation of problems you're trying to avoid.   The solution is to synchronise access to data that may be accessed at the same time by two or more threads.    Putting your functions into classes does not address that.

Comment: The `new/delete` is also a code smell. Multi-threading? You might want to go back a few chapters in your book. but if you picked up this style from a book, the book would be a bit suspect.

Comment: @SergeyA - what do you mean pass by value and return by value? Is that not what I'm doing? Is what I'm doing inefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both threads will run the same code (the code is shared).

But each thread will have its own private set of local variables. So the threads will not alter variables used by the other thread (if the variables are local to the function). Now if the variables are global then all bets are off.

Changing this to use classes will have absolutely no affect. Variables local to the function (and local to the object) will not be shared between threads. But global variables will still be shared.

There is a third type of variable (other than local (automatic storage duration), global (static storage duration)). This third type is thread local (thread storage duration). These are like global variables (they are not local to the function or object) but each thread has its own copy of the variable (so they don't interact like global variables) but they are not local to the function or object.